# Mock FtpClient for Unit Test - C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, ftp-client

I am writing unit tests in C# using the Moq framework. How can I mock the following line of code?

```cs
FtpClient client = new (Host, Username, Password, Port);
client.Connect();
```

What should I put in place of the above parameters, because I get an error `no such host is known or failed to connect to host`?

Comment: The server has to be running for FTPClient to connect.  You need to start a FtpListener in the test and connect to the listener.

Comment: You can wrap the functionality of the FTP in an interface which is implemented by the actual FTP client in your code and which you mock for your tests

Comment: Thank you. Can you please expand on this little more. How can the code for this be written?

Also, would it be possible to mock this using :
var mockFtp = new Mock<IFtpClient>();
mockFtp.Setup(x => x.Connect());

But I still get error, Failed to connect to host, when the host is an empty string. So will this error disappear if I replace the value with something else and what should I replace it with?